# How can I verify the options present in list of drop down using the Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, ide, selenium-ide

How can I verify the options present in list of drop down using the Selenium IDE?

For example A website has a drop down containing the following options:

- Regular
- Premium
- Annual
- Monthly

So I want to verify that the drop down contains following options list using Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Here example of code that shows how I check lists. `xpath_to_elements_of_drop_down_list` and should be replaced with corresponding xpath.

```
execute script | return ['Regular', 'Premium', 'Annual', 'Monthly'] | tabArr
store | 4 | nTabArr
store | 0 | j
store xpath count | xpath=xpath_to_elements_of_drop_down_list | n
assert | ${n} == ${N} | true
echo | Number of elements in the drop down list is correct |
while | ${j} < ${nTabArr} |
execute script | return ${tabArr}[${j}] | tabName
assert element present | xpath=path_to_elements_of_drop_down_list[contains(.,'${tabName}')] |
echo | ${tabName} is present in the drop down list|
execute script | return Number(${j}) + 1 | j
end | |
```